# How to I run a file on ubuntu which i compiled with Visual Studio on Windows for Linux

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio, compilation

I compiled a C# project in VS2022 with this settings:

[image: compilersettings]

It produced a file without a file extension.

How to I run in from linux?

Comment: If your project is .net core and you have the corresponding .net runtime installed on your Linux machine, have you tried `./myProjectName` (assuming you are in the executable's directory)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could flag your file as executable:

```bash
cd you_vs_code_foler/bin/Release/net6.0/publish/linux-x64

chmod +x your_programm

./your_programm
```

If you need to install .NET runtime at Ubuntu: try this:

```
sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-runtime-6.0
```

For further information and for other distrubtions please consult:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux

Comment: What's missing from the answer is a prerequisite. Since "Framework dependent" is used when publishing, .NET 6 runtime must be installed prior to running that executable.

Comment: You are right. I append my anwser for the missing prerequisite.